# Tag rename request: [freezing-vibration] to [freezing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

[freezing-vibration](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freezing-vibration) should be renamed to [freezing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freezing), possibly with a synonym pointing from the former to the latter (the series title is **Freezing**, not **Freezing Vibration**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonymized [freezing-vibration](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freezing-vibration) into [freezing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freezing) as a parent tag.